# Accessing elements of a map when using a variable key in Groovy

Tags: dictionary, groovy, groovy-console

I'm trying to replace some characters in a String From a map

**Case 1**

```
​map= ['O':'0', 'L':'1', 'Z':'2', 'E':'3']
"Hey".toUpperCase().toCharArray().each{
         print map.get(it,it)
     }
```

The result is

```
HEY
```

**Case 2** : I dont use `toCharArray()`

```
"Hey".toUpperCase().each{
        print map.get(it,it)
    }
```

The result is like expected

```
H3Y
```

So I tried several alternatives when using `toCharArray()`, and the only way to access the value is to use `map."$it"`

Why i can only use `map."$it"` to access my map when using `toCharArray()` ?

Comment: Not answering te question, but an alternative is `map = ['O':'0', 'L':'1', 'Z':'2', 'E':'3'].withDefault { it } ; println "Hey".toUpperCase().collect { map[it] }.join()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to get a value from a map using a `char` whilst every key there are `String`, and they are not equals:

```
assert !'E'.equals('E' as char)
```

`$it` works because it is converted to String:

```
e = 'E' as char

assert "$e".toString().equals('E')
```

(Note the `toString()` is needed, otherwise the comparison will happen between `String` and `GStringImpl` which are not equals)

Comment: and when I use `each` without `toCharArray()` in **Case 2**, the `it` is a String ?

Comment: Yep. `$ groovy -e ' "foo".each { assert it in String } '`